# Vector bundle associated to orthogonal flag

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, grassmannians, projective-varieties

Let $V$ be a $(2n+1)$-dimensional complex vector space endowed with a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form $q:V\times V\to \mathbb C$.

Fix the notation:
$$
OG(n-1,n,V):=\{W_{n-1}\subset W_n\subset W_n^\perp \subset W_{n-1}^\perp \subset  V : \dim W_i=i\}
$$
where $W^\perp :=\{ v \in V : q(v,w)=0 \text{ for all }w\in W\}$. It has two natural projections
$$
p:OG(n-1,n,V) \to OG(n-1,V)
$$
$$
q:OG(n-1,n,V) \to OG(n,V)
$$
and $p^{-1}(*)=\mathbb P^1$, $q^{-1}(*)=\mathbb P^{n-1}$. Thus $OG(n-1,n,V)$ has two projective bundle structures. The structure given by $q$ comes from the tautological bundle over $OG(n,V)$.

I do not understand which vector bundle is compatible with the projective bundle structure of $p$. Explicitly, I am looking for a rank 2 vector bundle $F$ over $OG(n-1,V)$ such that
$$
\mathbb P(F)=OG(n-1,n,V).
$$